# ASP.net sitemap fails to navigate?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to Asp.net and I had some trouble with menu navigation.
I had the Web.sitemap

```
<siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home" description="Home">

<siteMapNode url="~/Default" title="Home" description="Go to the homepage" />

<siteMapNode url="~/Reviews/Default" title="Reviews" description="Reviews published on this site">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Reviews/AllByGenre" title="By Genre" description="All Reviews Grouped by Genre" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Reviews/All" title="All Reviews" description="All Reviews" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode url="~/About/Default" title="About" description="About this Site">
  <siteMapNode url="~/About/Contact" title="Contact Us" description="Contact Us" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/About/AboutUs" title="About Us" description="About Us" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode url="~/Login" title="Login" description="Log in to this web site" />
```

and the start page `Default.aspx` gives 
[image]

But it just gives `HTTP Error 404.0 not found error`when I try to navigate. URL is `http://localhost:24186/About/AboutUs`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url ="~/About/Default" . Try add the .aspx like

```
url="~/About/Default.aspx"
```

I am not sure though. Cant see issue otherwise. I normally add the .aspx and i think it should be there.